# The view **.views.upload_file didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django-views

I have the two methods:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(file):
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        sample = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel')
        return sample

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            result=handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return render('show_imported.html',{'list': result})
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
        return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and the following view here:

**upload.html:**

{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Mebadas/themes/style.css' %}" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
<form method="POST" action="">
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>

    {% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

and show_imported.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Mebadas/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css' %}" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
{% render_table list %}
</body>
</html>
```

When running upload_file it returns

> ValueError at /upload/ The view Mebadas.views.upload_file didn't
>   return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning any response if your method is POST and if the form is invalid.

i.e There is no else block if the `form.is_valid()` returns False